# Equating pointer value is changing pointer reference

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, nodes

```
struct node
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(frames*sizeof(char));
}*start,*current;
```

Then I have allocated memory equal to `node` to start.

```
[...]//Assigned values to start node.
current = start;//Current points to start
node *temp = new node();//temp will point a newly created node
*temp = *current;//    COPYING VALUES OF CURRENT TO TEMP
[...]
```

I want to create a new node, make `temp` point to it and copy values of `current` (here current is pointing to start) to temp.

BUT this is making temp point `current` (here `start`) instead. 
Frustrated. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What language is this? It's certainly not C ...

Comment: Doing in c++ but i dont see any reason for it not to run in c

Comment: @SrujanBarai You know there's no  `new` in C, right? And that you can't have a function call in a structure declaration like that? Not sure you can do that in C++, either.

Comment: Function call in a structure is working mate. c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two solutions

1. Change *temp=*current to temp=current. Doing this, you can access values of "current" using "temp" as these two pointers are now referring to the same memory location. Caution, changing value by using "current" or "temp" will cause to change in value in both pointers as they are referring to same memory location.
2. Use memcpy. It will copy values from one memory location to other. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) is the reference. Now you have two independent copies of values.

Comment: Something i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`*temp = *current` should be `temp = current`.

Comment: this will make `temp` point `current` isnt it? I want to add its vales

Comment: Rather it will make `temp` point where `current` is pointing. My bad